# Validation Form + Redirect

Tags: javascript, forms, contact-form

I am trying to add a redirection page to the form after submitting.

for now after submitting the form, it shows a small text message "thank you for sending", but i would like it to redirect to another page.
Is there a way to add a redirect function to either the validation script or directly in the form?

```
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <title>Test</title>
            <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                function validateForm() {

                var x=document.forms["myForm"]["FirstName"].value;
                if (x==null || x=="")
                  {
                  alert("Name is missing");
                  return false;
                  }

                var y=document.forms["myForm"]["MobilePhone"].value;
                if (y==null || y=="") {
                  alert("Mobile is missing");
                  return false;
                  }
                    var y=document.forms["myForm"]["Email"].value;
                if (y==null || y=="") {
                  alert("Mail is missing");
                  return false;
                  }
                    }
            </script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="background">
                <div id="Background">
                    <div id="contact">
                    <form name="myForm" method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8" action="http://clients.frontask.co.il/12137/Pages/Utilities/WebToLead.aspx?type=form" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
                    <table border="0">
                        <tbody>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="FirstName"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 94px;">
                        <input type="text" name="AccountName" />
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="MobilePhone"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 94px;">
                        <input type="text" name="Title" />
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                        <td>
                        <input type="text" name="Email" />
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 94px;padding-top: 11px;">
                            <select name="Address">
                              <option>1</option>
                              <option>2</option>
                              <option>3</option>
                              <option>4</option>
                              <option>5</option>
                              <option>6</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                            <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top:5px;">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="MailingList" checked="checked"/>
                        </td>
                        <td style="padding-right: 94px;padding-top: 11px;">
                        <input type="submit" value="send" />
                        </td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>


                    <input type="hidden" name="SystemID" value="2e1a82a2-350f-44fe-b571-0fc344f12fbf" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ProcessDefinitionStepID" value="PP60400279_0B8F_41F8_ABCC_15834568F4BE" />
    <input type="hidden" name="RedirectTo" value="" />
    <input name="enc" type="hidden" value="&#9760;" />
    <input type="hidden" name="UpdateExistingDetails" value="false" />
    <input type="hidden" name="ContactTypes" value="PM8BA799EF_23FF_4679_8484_D603E2DC8BB0" />


                    </form>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
     </body>
     </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

After submitting, using the below code redirect the page.

```
window.location.href = 'give the url which you want to redirect';
```

Add this to end of the `validateForm()`

```
alert("thank you for sending");
window.location.href = 'give the url which you want to redirect';
```

Comment: Hello Praveen, thank you for your answer.

i tried to add the code before the closing of the validation form, but nothing changed, can you please direct me where exactly i should put this code?

Comment: @Pavel Can you check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/8dwsK/.  Let me know if you need any help.